# should an after_save callback run after an update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry to ask such an abvious question but 'Should an after_save callback run after you update a set of objects from the rails console?' I would think unambiguously yes but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should, but it depends on how you're updating, e.g., [using update_all skips callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#updating-an-object

Comment: I'm doing via update_all which looks like it skips callbacks. I'll update to just update with a block